# How should you cite yourself when there are more than 15 authors?

Tags: citations, citation-style

I am not one of the primary authors of the article, and there are more than 15 authors for the paper I am referring to.

How should I include the paper in my CV? Should all authors be cited? How can I neatly highlight my contribution without having to enlist all authors?

(This is only necessary, so I can be as economical as possible with the available space.)

Comment: Why do you have space restrictions on a CV?

Comment: @Buffy I have a 2-page limitation for the application I am working on

Comment: Headline: Publications. I don't think anyone cares whether you are listed in the actual citation or included in "et al".

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you have space constraints, one way I have seen this done is:

> First A., ... Plesca, A.-M., ... Senior A. (2022) "A title." *Journal*.

The first author lets someone find the full citation, and the senior author(s) contextualize whose lab(s) the work was performed in (if that's how your field uses last authors). If there are other important collaborators who don't fall in one of those roles, you can include them too.

If you are second or third (for example), you can list all authors until you get to yourself then insert the ellipsis.

Comment: Yes. This seems like the correct approach.

Comment: I thought that the OP's question is interesting and I agree completely with the answer provided. But I also think that there is something of a general nature that others can learn. Specifically, the many and various citation style guidelines (e.g., Vancouver, Chicago, APA,, etc) are all developed with journals, publication workflow, and standardization in mind. But there is *no reason at all* not to alter them to suit atypical situations when they arise. The adaptations are likely to be ad-hoc, but they can still be sensible, as nicely shown in the proffered answer.

Answer (score 16):

I tend to use the standard "Jones *et al.*, 2007" format, and then add a note to say it includes me. Something like this:

> Jones *et al.* (including terdon), 2007

Of course, even this isn't necessary. If you are listing publications in your own C.V., then you are claiming authorship by definition, so simply mentioning the Jones paper will be enough: you wouldn't be listing it if your name were not among the authors so you don't even really need to highlight it in any way.

Answer (score 5):

I have also seen *i.a.* for Latin *inter alia*, meaning among others.

Something like:

> First Author, *i.a.* John Smith. "A great Paper about something important", Science **3** (2022).

Comment: Doesn't *inter alia* (typically?) mean "among other things"?

Comment: It just means among others, could be things, people, what ever you desire.

And I've seen this used in this context a few times.

Comment: @d3lt4_papa Actually it [does](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alius#Declension) mean *things* (the correct form for people would be *inter alios* or *inter alias* depending on the grammatical gender). Not that I doubt that you saw it used like that, but it is a grammatical mistake...